# Custom styling Kendo Treeview node text in trees loaded from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

Let's say I want to add a red background to all tree nodes matching a certain text, in a dynamically loaded Kendo UI TreeView. How can I do this?

It's easy to [customize node styles when instantiating trees from HTML](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index), but for trees [loaded from a local data source](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/overview#creating-a-treeview-with-data-binding-to-a-local-data-source) or [read from a remote HierarchicalDataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/overview#binding-to-a-remote-hierarchicaldatasource), there seem to be no way to alter the item's text *per-node* style:

- the [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-template) option applies to all nodes in the tree
- the [spriteCssClass](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/overview#item-definition) applies only to the node's icon

How can I achieve something like this while loading the tree from JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you just use jQuery for it. Like this:

```
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        ...
        dataBound: function (e) {
            var text = "Your Text";
            e.sender.element.find("span.k-in:contains(" + text + ")").css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

Working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/oxUKI

Comment: Nice. I've glossed over the [Treeview documentation for databound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-dataBound) because it didn't mention styling the node at all. The Scheduler doc for databind does mention how to [modify element styling on databound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/scheduler/how-to/modify-event-styling-on-databound).